# Inconsistent behavior when generating PDF in a java web application

Tags: java, pdf, web-applications, pdf-generation, itext

I am using the iText PDF library to generate a dynamic PDF document containing a `PdfPTable`. I use a servlet to stream the PDF to the browser. It works, but inconsistently. Sometimes it looks as if the browser loads the plugin for Acrobat reader, but the report isn't displayed. Is this an iText or an Adobe Reader problem?

Here is the code I use to generate the PDF and stream it to the browser.

```
public void generatePdfReport() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OutputStream out;
    buildPdfReport(agentPayroll, salesSummaryData, baos);


    res.setContentType("application/pdf");
    res.setContentLength(baos.size()); 
    out = res.getOutputStream();

    baos.writeTo(out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}

private void buildPdfReport(ByteArrayOutputStream baos) {
    float cellBorderWidth;

    cellBorderWidth = 1F;

    document= new Document(PageSize.LETTER.rotate(), 2, 2, 2, 2);
    pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);

    document.open();

    PdfPCell cell;
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);
    table.setSpacingBefore(5.0F);
    table.setHorizontalAlignment(PdfPTable.ALIGN_LEFT);
    table.setTotalWidth(780F);
    table.setLockedWidth(true);
    while(someCondition == true) {
        // Generate some cells and add to table
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("SomeText", timesRomanFont6Pt));
        cell.setBorderWidth(cellBorderWidth);
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(PdfPTable.ALIGN_LEFT);
        cell.setVerticalAlignment(PdfPTable.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        table.addCell(cell);
    }
}
```

The column widths add up to the total width set for the pdf of 780:

```
    private static final float[] columnWidths = {188, 
            37, 
            88, 
            50, 
            37, 
            25, 
            35, 
            35, 
            35, 
            30, 
            32, 
            26, 
            35, 
            60, 
            46, 
            26  
    };
```

I can't seem to find out what the problem is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks All,

Greg

Comment: I don't see you closing the document. Close it at the end of `buildPdfReport`.

Comment: The code sample doesn't show us everything we need to know. For instance: where do you close the document? Are you defining the document at the Servlet level? What happens when there are concurrent users? This could be a problem caused by something different than iText or Adobe Reader. It could be a more general design problem.

Comment: 0

down vote

accept
 

I'm sorry, I left out the document.close() out of the example but I am closing it in my code as you suggested. I am defining the document at the servlet level. So far I am the only user.

Thanks,

Greg

Comment: *but I am closing it in my code* - Where do you do so? Please edit your question to include this. The reason I insist is that using the document, closing it, and using the `ByteArrayOutputStream` it writes into must occur in the correct order.

Comment: I close the document before I close the ByteArrayOutputStream